# Insert "element" among other "elements" of the array (loop) php

Tags: php

my code causes the images to appear randomly within the page.
But how to insert an "element" (in my case would be a div) between these images?

```
<?php
$myImagesList = array (
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png',
    'image3.png',
    'image4.png'
);

shuffle ($myImagesList);
for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {

echo '<img src="/image/' . $myImagesList[$i] . '" width="200" height="140" border="0" />';
}
?>
```

Example:

**The original code displays the images as follows:**

image3.png image4.png image2.png image1.png

F5 refresh page

image2.png image1.png image4.png image3.png

F5 refresh page

image4.png image2.png image3.png image1.png

**I needed it this way:**

image2.png image1.png

content

image4.png image3.png

F5 refresh page

image4.png image2.png

content

image1.png image3.png

F5 refresh page

image2.png image3.png

content

image4.png image1.png

Comment: If you only want to show two, why `$i<4` ? Show two, then start the loop again, or check if $i is 2 and show your extra content.

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this...

```
 $myImagesList = array (
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png',
    'image3.png',
    'image4.png'
 );
 shuffle ($myImagesList);

 $i = 0;
 foreach ($myImagesList as $img) {

    $i++;

    if ($i % 3 === 0) { /* show content */ }

    echo '<img src="/image/' . $img . '" width="200" height="140" border="0" />';

 }
```

This will give you the content section every third iteration, no matter the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a `div`(content) between those two pairs of images - add additional condition into your loop:

```
...
for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
    if ($i == 1) echo '<div>some content ...</div>';
    echo '<img src="/image/' . $myImagesList[$i] . '" width="200" height="140" border="0" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with the most readable solution - the one that doesn't make you fall and debug later when changing something.

```
$splitAtNumber = 2; // or dynamically use count($myImagesList) / 2 or ....

// output first part of the array
for ($i = 0; $i < $splitAtNumber; $i++) {
    echo '<img src="/image/' . $myImagesList[$i] . '" width="200" height="140" border="0" />';
}

// Output your content
echo 'content';

// Output second part of the array
for ($i = splitAtNumber; $i < count($myImagesList); $i++) {
    echo '<img src="/image/' . $myImagesList[$i] . '" width="200" height="140" border="0" />';
}
```