# Continue the loop elsewhere in the site

Tags: php

this code causes the images to be displayed on a rotating basis on the site.

```
<?php
$myImagesList = array (
 'image1.png' ,
  'image2.png' ,
  'image3.png' ,
  'image4.png' ,
  'image5.png' ,
  'image6.png' ,
  'image7.png' ,
  'image8.png' ,
  'image9.png' ,
  'image10.png'
);

shuffle ($myImagesList);
echo '<div style = "background: #0600ff" class = "div02">';
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    if ($i < 5) {
      echo '' . $myImagesList[$i] . '';
    }
    if ($i == 5) {
       echo '</div>';

        echo '<div style = "background: #0600ff" class = "div02">';
     }  
     if ($i > 5) {
        echo '' . $myImagesList[$i] . '';
      }
  }
 echo '</div>';
?>
```

CONTENT

**It is that way in html page**
[image]

But how to break this code so that the loop with rotating images continues elsewhere on the site?

**something like this**

```
<?php
RANDOM IMAGES 
?>

XXX HTML CODE XXX

<?php
CONTINUOUS RANDOM IMAGE
?>
```

**imagem:**
[image]

Comment: This sounds like more of a style (CSS) issue.

Comment: Change `10` to `5` then start another loop later on, starting at `5`.

Comment: This seems remarkably similar to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285086/insert-element-among-other-elements-of-the-array-loop-php where you had 3 answers already

Comment: Chris85 but the images will be repeated

Comment: rjdown he question in this topic is different. I want to divide the loop in 2 different codes, without the images repeated. It would be loop divided into two parts. The top and bottom part (continuing rotation pictures)

Comment: I've posted an example as an answer take a look. Use the `@` to tag users.

Comment: hello, thanks for you help, but how to break this loop 10 rotating images into two parts, so I show 5 pictures at the top of the site (header) and 5 images at the bottom of the site (footer)?

something like this: http://pastebin.com/fPxt0zEH

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 `for` loops and do whatever you want in between the second loop.

```
<?php
$myImagesList = array (
 'image1.png' ,
  'image2.png' ,
  'image3.png' ,
  'image4.png' ,
  'image5.png' ,
  'image6.png' ,
  'image7.png' ,
  'image8.png' ,
  'image9.png' ,
  'image10.png'
);
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
     echo $myImagesList[$i] . "\n";
}
echo 'Start second loop' . "\n";
//note no reassignment of $i
for ($i; $i<10; $i++) {
     echo $myImagesList[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/603402

Comment: hello, thanks for you help, but how to break this loop 10 rotating images into two parts, so I show 5 pictures at the top of the site (header) and 5 images at the bottom of the site (footer)?

something like this: http://pastebin.com/fPxt0zEH

Comment: This answer does that, doesn't it?