# Split a php rotation code

Tags: php

this loop displays 10 images in rotation on a page.

```
<?php
$myImagesList = array (
 'image1.png' ,
  'image2.png' ,
  'image3.png' ,
  'image4.png' ,
  'image5.png' ,
  'image6.png' ,
  'image7.png' ,
  'image8.png' ,
  'image9.png' ,
  'image10.png'
);

shuffle ($myImagesList);
for ($i=0; $i<15; $i++) {
echo '' . $myImagesList[$i] . '';
}
?>
```

But how to divide it into two parts, so I show 5 pictures at the top of the page, and 5 images in the page footer?
something like this:

```
<Body>
<Div id = "site">
<Div id = "header">
 
 
<? php
XXXX XXXX Show 5 images
?>
 
 
</ Div>
<Div id = "content">
Text
</ Div>
<Div id = "footer">
 
 
<? php
XXXX XXXX Show 5 images
?>
 
 
</ Div>
</ Div>
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continue the loop elsewhere in the site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296947/continue-the-loop-elsewhere-in-the-site)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your iteration starting point:

```
<?php
$myImageList = [
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png',
    'image3.png',
    'image4.png',
    'image5.png',
    'image6.png',
    'image7.png',
    'image8.png',
    'image9.png',
    'image10.png',
];

shuffle($myImageList);
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) echo $myImagesList[$i] . '<br>'; ?>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<?php for ($i = 5; $i < 10; $i++) echo $myImagesList[$i] . '<br>'; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to show precisely half on top and half on bottom regardless of how many pieces are in `$myImagesList` then you can do this:

```
<?php
$myImagesList = array (
 'image1.png' ,
  'image2.png' ,
  'image3.png' ,
  'image4.png' ,
  'image5.png' ,
  'image6.png' ,
  'image7.png' ,
  'image8.png' ,
  'image9.png' ,
  'image10.png'
);

shuffle ($myImagesList);

$firstHalf = array_slice($myImagesList, 0, round((count($myImagesList) / 2), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP));
$secondHalf = array_slice($myImagesList, round((count($myImagesList) / 2), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP));

// First half
foreach($firstHalf as $v)
{
    echo $v;
}

// Second half
foreach($secondHalf as $v)
{
    echo $v;
}
```

If an odd number of elements exists in `$myImagesList` then the first half will show one image more than the bottom half.

Answer (score 0):

Array slice with helper function.

```
<?php

$myImageList = [
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png',
    'image3.png',
    'image4.png',
    'image5.png',
    'image6.png',
    'image7.png',
    'image8.png',
    'image9.png',
    'image10.png',
];

function display_images(array $images, $base_path) {
?>
    <?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $base_path . '/' . $image ?>">
    <?php } ?>
<?php
}


shuffle($myImageList);
display_images(array_slice($myImageList, 0, 5), '/foo');
display_images(array_slice($myImageList, 5, 5), '/foo');
```